# Is there a way to reset or refresh the yaw only for an iphone gyroscope application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, gyroscope

I built an application for gyroscope, and the yaw is always measuring from the point of where I turned on the application.  I would like to be able to bring the measurement to zero or re-calibrate the Yaw measurement only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, although not the most advanced or refined, is to hold off on setting the motion manager reference frame until the user strikes a button identifying that he/she is ready to begin, calibrate, etc.  This way yaw = 0 at the point the button is struck and not the point at which the application is loaded.